# Displaying subject age instead of capture date in photos

Tags: digital

I am creating a photo album for my puppy.
Usually a date is recorded when a photo is taken. Check [this link](http://0.tqn.com/d/graphicssoft/1/0/p/Z/removedate01.jpg) out.

I want to make a photo album in such a way that each photo carries the age of puppy (i.e. 3 months old, 5 months 4 days, 1 year, etc...), instead of the date when the photo was taken.

As of now, I can think of two options:

1. Any camera that can accept user input (like the birthdate of a
   person), then auto-calculate by subtracting "date picture
   taken"-"birthdate", and putting that tag into the image via
   caption/something else?
2. Dedicated script (maybe via exiftool/[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org)).

I have no experience with any of the above options. Could someone explain me how to perform this step-by-step from scratch?

Can a camera or smartphone camera accept the birthdate of my puppy? (I want to feed in the birthdate.)

I am using windows XP hence relevant solution is more comfortable.

Comment: Do you really have so many that doing this manually is a problem?

Comment: Yeah, i have more than 400 images & still counter is ON. capturing more & more images.

Comment: Is python an option?

Comment: I can try python if you can suggest me how to read images & write back.

Comment: 400 images is a lot.  You need to sit down and cull that down to the 10-15 good images actually worth keeping or maybe just the 5 or so images worth showing others.  You might also want to think a little before pressing the shutter button again.

Answer (score 1):

Most Panasonic Lumix compact cameras have an option to set the scene mode to "Baby" or "Pet". This lets you set the name and date of birth of the baby or pet. Then the camera will display the name and age when taking a photo, or when viewing photos in playback mode. The age is displayed in years, months, and days.

Then set the camera to playback mode, and use the "text stamp" feature. This will let you stamp the photo with the name or age, so it is part of the image, and will be shown on the photo after downloading it to a computer.

If you don't text stamp the photos before downloading it, I'm not sure how the name or age is recorded. It seems it is possible to use the PhotoFunStudio software (bundled with the camera) to add text stamps for name or age.

Comment: Thanks. Recently i also come to know there are some NIKON DSLR cameras which can do display age thru some setting. I am not sure about smart cameras perhaps few latest cameras may have such feature (via en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TouchWiz) also.
Unfortunately i dont own any such cameras. My camera is S100 Canon.